# What does "layering of roles" mean in this sentence?

Tags: character-analysis, italian-language, literary-criticism, luigi-pirandello

What does ["layering of roles"](https://books.google.com/books?id=0Qv2nuJF7yYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q=%22layering%20of%20roles%22&f=false) precisely mean in the following sentence quoted from *Pirandello and the Crisis of Modern Consciousness*
by Anthony Francis Caputi?

> For the generation of Neveux, Jean Giraudoux, and Jean Anouilh, the term “Pirandellisme” meant “pure intellectual game,” and Pirandellian structures meant characters seen as **a layering of roles**.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main themes of Pirandello's works is certainly the fragmentation of the Ego, see *Uno, nessuno, cento mila*, *Il fu Mattia Pascal*, etc. This fragmentation is metaphorized with the concept of masks.

According to Pirandello, people wear different masks depending on the situation they are in; these masks will be more or less different from our true identity. The stratification therefore indicates, in my opinion, a multitude of attitudes with which the characters are dressed, as if in layers.

So, **layering of roles** means literally layering the masks we created to look in a certain way, even for the vision of ourselves, not in a superficial but in a  deep way, sometimes the characters of pirandello are convinced that they are what they represent and they forget who they were (*il fu mattia pascal*).